# Spring Boot + Keycloak RBAC

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, rbac

I have a spring boot application and a keycloak instance.

The spring boot application runs in 8083 port and has some endpoints-resources and I want all these to be accessed upon authentication but also authorization having a certain role

Let's assume that we have some users and the role named `myrole` assigned to one or more of them.

I have the below configuration in my spring boot app in order to make all my endpoints to be accessible from every user that has the `myrole` role assigned.

SecurityConfig.java

```
package mypackage;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().hasAuthority("myrole"));
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .build();
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
keycloak.uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=myclient
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=${keycloak.uri}
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=${keycloak.uri}
```

I test it with postman and every time I get a 403 Forbidden response. The request has the bearer token in Authorization header.

What do I miss?

Comment: Put the token in jwt.io and see if the claim is being passed.

Comment: @K.Nicholas This is the output: https://t.ly/zqcom Can you provide me some help?

Comment: I tried the answer here and it worked. [Using a GrantedAuthoritiesMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities-grantedauthoritiesmapper)

Comment: @K.Nicholas It didn't work. I quit :-)

Comment: Probably for the best.

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed! It just needed to add the below method in SecurityConfig to retrieve properly the user's roles from access token so I changed the configuration to this:

```js
package eu.seafarers.config;

import com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated();
                })
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverterForKeycloak() {
        Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = jwt -> {

            Object client = jwt.getClaim("realm_access");

            LinkedTreeMap<String, List<String>> clientRoleMap = (LinkedTreeMap<String, List<String>>) client;

            List<String> clientRoles = new ArrayList<>(clientRoleMap.get("roles"));

            return clientRoles.stream()
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        };

        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();

        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);

        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

## [RTFM](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction)

Also, you shouldn't need OAuth2 client dependencies and configuration properties on a REST API authorized with access tokens.

If you want something simpler that what is exposed in the doc, you can have a look at [this starter I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons):

```xml
<!-- you should have this 2 already -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- this is an additional Spring Boot starter compatible with Boot 3.2.1 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
keycloak.uri: http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm

# spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.* properties are ignored by spring-addons, you can remove it.

# spring.security.oauth2.client.* properties are used by spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client 
# which is of no use to secure a REST API with access tokens. You should remove it.

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${keycloak.uri}
          username-claim: preferred_username
          authorities:
          - path: $.realm_access.roles
            # you can add here some basic transformation like adding a "ROLE_" prefix or force role names to uppercase
          # you can add more entries with other JSON path to ressource_access (client) roles
        # resource server with nothing accessible to anonymous and no CORS configuration
        resourceserver:
          permit-all:
          cors:
```

If you're using method security (decorate your `@Controller` classes or methods with `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('myrole')")`), then all you need is:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

If you prefer to use `AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry` in your conf, then what you need is:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    ResourceServerExpressionInterceptUrlRegistryPostProcessor expressionInterceptUrlRegistryPostProcessor() {
        return (AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry registry) -> registry
            .anyRequest().hasAuthority("myrole");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good morning! This starter you wrote didn't work. It always returns 401. I'm on trying the doc's method. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: The doc's method didn't work either.. Something nasty should probably exist in configuration. Can't explain it otherwise

Comment: Unless you provide some DEBUG logs and details about how you proceeded (what did you use to send the request, how you got the token, how you authorized the request, etc.), noone can a thing for you.

Comment: For instance, I'm curious why you report a 401 here (maybe you're using your browser or an expired token) and a 403 in the comments to your question. Also, from what I see in your token in the comments to your question, you intend to send requests from Angular (allowed origin on port 4200).Angular apps are bad OAuth2 clients (public), you should use a BFF configured as confidential client and with something to translate from session security to tokens security: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff

Comment: I do use a BFF so this is a nice direction to solve the problem. I'll check it, thanks!

Comment: Maybe should you read the OAuth2 essentials [in the parent directory](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) of the tutorial I linked, with special care to which requests are authorized with session and CSRF cookies and which are authorized with tokens, because this changes depending on requests being sent to the BFF or to a REST API behind it